# google calendar sync using google api

Tags: export, google-calendar-api, synchronization

i want to sync google calendar with facebook friend birthday

and i know how to export my friends birthday with java code

does anybody know how to sync google calendar with this exported ics file??(in programic approach)

any method to access google calendar URL sync?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/